# HTML Arrow Entity, Dec, or Hex Code for FPDF

Tags: entity, fpdf

I tried to use html arrow for my fpdf document but it doesnt work

i tried some of this code, none of it work, it only work for some entity only like ©
but when i wanna use ↠ or → it doesnt work, i dont know why.

this is my code

```
$str = "&rarr";
$str = utf8_decode($str);
$str = html_entity_decode($str);
```

```
$huha =  iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252',$str);
```

```
$huha = iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252', html_entity_decode("&rarr;"));
```

```
$huha = html_entity_decode("&#169;", ENT_XHTML,"ISO-8859-1");
```

Comment: *"i dont know why"* Do you think all characters belong to windows-1252?

Comment: I'm sorry i just following tutorial from internet, so i need to change windows-1252? To what?

Comment: Is ISO-8859-1 part of it too? Like windows-1252? Because ISO-8859-1 doesnt work as well

Comment: See [this](http://www.fpdf.org/?go=script&id=4) for informations about the standard fonts.

Comment: Thanks you man! You solved this thank you so much 

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the example to get all of your font characters.
This is how you use it

```
$pdf->SetFont('Symbol','',11);
$pdf->Cell(0,5.5,chr(36),0,1); //This will display the $ character
```

The following is a list of commonly used characters
33:!
34:"
35:#
36:$
37:%
38:&

@Olivier had the right answer I just wanted to put an example on this post.

Reference: [Here](http://www.fpdf.org/?go=script&id=4)